# How to convert multiple date formats to one standard format in Excel using Java POI

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi, date-formatting

[Expected OutputFile FOrmat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovtod.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUtZy.jpg)    Input File                 Output File(Expected)

```
JoiningDate                JoiningDate             
1/4/2017                    4/1/2017                   
2/4/2017                    4/2/107
...                         ...
...                         ...
13/04/2017                  4/13/2017
14/04/2017                  4/14/2017
```

I have a input excel file in which there is a column which is having dates in multiple format as shown above, First few rows are having its cell type as "General" and last few rows are Date celltype. I tried using below code but at a time any one gets converted I want all rows to be converted to single format.

```
    import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
        import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
        import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCreationHelper;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
        import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


      class DateFormatDemo1{ 
        public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, ParseException
        {
            OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("C:\\DateFormatIssue\\SourceFile\\S.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg); 
            XSSFCreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);      // Create spreadsheet in workbook
            Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
            Cell cell = null;
            Row row=null;
            row=iterator.next();
            int pos=11;
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                row=iterator.next();

                cell= row.getCell(pos-1);


                XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
                cellStyle.setDataFormat( createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("M/dd/yyyy")); // set the format of the date  
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");     
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle2 = (XSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
            cellStyle.setDataFormat( createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("d/M/yyyy"));      
                Date d=null;


                /** below if block converts lower rows, dates which are in format d/M/yyyy (15/04/2017) to M/d/yyyy (4/15/2017)**/
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {    

                    d= sdf.parse(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    cell.setCellValue(d);
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);       

                }


                else  if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                {
                   Below code enable if want to convert upper rows i.e. 1/4/2017 to 4/1/2017 **/
                    /* 
                      if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue()); 
                        cell.setCellValue(cell.getDateCellValue()); 
                        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.setCellValue(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 
                    }
    */

                }
            }




            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\DateFormatIssue\\OutputFile\\output.xlsx"));
            wb.write(outFile);
            wb.close();
            outFile.close();
            pkg.close();




        }}
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: How do you know they are in multiple date formats? Maybe they are really all `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy please check attached images.

Comment: @VikasJ That just tells me that Excel is assuming the date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`, and when it isn't, then it just treats the value as a string. But every date you have shown us is a valid date in DD/MM/YYYY format. What happens if you tell Excel that the date is in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: Excel uses you system settings to interpret dates. If your system says that dates are in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, that is how you have to enter them in order for Excel to parse them properly. Excel is smart enough to know that it is common to use 2 digit years, or `-` as a separator, but the order of the parts is critical. If you have 1/4/2018, is that January 4, 2018, or April 1, 2018? It depends on if you are in USA or Europe. Your system setting tells Excel which to use.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Thanks for your input. Yes u are right Excel is assuming the date format is MM/DD/YYYY, and when it isn't, then it just treats the value as a string. Because rows which have data as 1/04/2017 its cell type in excel is Date and 15/04/2017 cell type is General. And when I say in SimpleDateformat that date is in DD/MM/YYYY then it prints 1/04/2017...12/04/2017  **1/01/2017** **1/01/2017** now here I was expecting value to be 13/01/2017, 14/01/2017 and so on.

Comment: Also in Excel there is a setting if you go Data tab->Text to Columns and do next ->next on 1st and 2nd step in 3rd step there is a option that lets you set date format in that select Date option and from drop down **DMY** it will print all dates in proper format like 4/1/2017 4/2/2017..  4/12/2017 4/13/2017 4/14/2017 and so on. This is what i need but through java code

Comment: I am going to write this as an answer because sometimes comments go away, and then this won't benefit anyone else.

Comment: So in existing code I have to say If dateformat from source file is in M/dd/yyyy(cellType - Date) OR dd/M/yyyy(cell Type - General) convert it to M/dd/yyyy just like what excel does internally in setting that i mentioned above. Not able to figure out how to do that

Comment: I am going to write this as an answer because sometimes comments go away, and then this won't benefit anyone else.  **Where is the answer?**

Comment: working on it now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the dates you have shown us fit into DD/MM/YYYY format which is common in Europe, and possibly other areas. But when you manually enter a value in Excel, it uses the local system settings to detect a date. It appears that your local date format is MM/DD/YYYY which is the format used in the USA. Unfortunately some DD/MM/YYYY dates will parse "correctly" in MM/DD/YYYY format, but will give the wrong date, while the dates that don't parse correctly will just be treated as strings. This appears to be what you are seeing.

```
for USA
Date entered     Excel Type     Display             Text
------------     ----------     ---------------     ----------------
1/4/2018         Date                  1/4/2018     January 4, 2018
2/4/2018         Date                  2/4/2018     February 4, 2018
15/4/2018        General        15/4/2018           Unknown

for Europe
Date entered     Excel Type     Display             Text
------------     ----------     ---------------     ---------------
1/4/2018         Date                  1/4/2018     April 1, 2018
2/4/2018         Date                  2/4/2018     April 2, 2018
15/4/2018        Date                 15/4/2018     April 15, 2018
```

It appears to me that all the dates you gave given me fit DMY, and it makes no sense that anyone would actually mix the two without telling you which were MDY, and which were DMY because there is no way to tell except that some dates won't work in the other format (those with a day > 12).

So treat them all as DMY, and when creating the spreadsheet use `Text to Columns`, and tell the wizard that the column contains Dates in DMY format. That should provide the correct date value for the entire column. Notice that the D and M values will switch positions for all dates in the column. Now you can process it with POI and not have to deal with weird conversions.